How can I mount a Deore XT brake caliper on a flat-mount fork?
I'm looking to build up a flat-mount frame (front and rear) with Shimano Deore XT components.
While there exists an in-series flat mount brake caliper for Deore XT (BR-M8110), this seems to only be meant as rear brake. Can I just go ahead and mount it to an adapter (Y-8N230000) and that to my fork? Is this somehow a bad idea?
Or would I be better off using a post-mount adapter (e.g. SM-MA-F160P/D) and going with the post-mount caliper (BR-M8100)?

I would not be surprised that they marketed as rear because they simply don’t have the adapter that Shimano considers as required for front brakes.

It’s only meant as a rear brake because the intent of that groupset mini-series is for those XC mountain bikes where the rear caliper is flat mounted. AFAIK all suspension forks are post mount and so there isn’t a need for a front MTB flat mount caliper.

Either would be fine but a flat mount caliper on a flat mount fork will work better. If you wish to build up your own system, you can use any of the road calipers (all flat mount) with the XT levers.
Front and rear caliper castings are the same so the XT flat mount caliper can work in either location, don't worry about how it is marketed.

Many thanks for the feedback. I was not aware of road/MTB lever/caliper compatibility as Shimano does not discuss such combinations in their compatibility charts (or I did not look in the right places). But the flat-mount XT caliper does look a lot like a rebranded Ultegra (R8000) part.
